# Can't fit a table in beamer

Tags: beamer, r, rstudio

This is the output of the stargazer package that I did in R. However, I can't make the table fit in my beamer presentation.

Here is the code:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: dom, nov 24, 2019 - 17:40:05
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Tabela 1} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Variável dependete} \\ 
\cline{2-10} 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Anos de estudo (25 anos ou mais)} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9)\\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Percentual de domicilios com abastecimento de água potável & 0.739$^{***}$ & 0.287$^{***}$ & 0.308$^{***}$ & 0.286$^{***}$ & 0.196$^{***}$ & 0.203$^{***}$ & 0.136$^{***}$ & 0.196$^{***}$ & 0.332$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.025) & (0.023) & (0.040) & (0.024) & (0.022) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Analfabestismo &  & $-$0.247$^{***}$ & $-$0.246$^{***}$ & $-$0.216$^{***}$ & $-$0.202$^{***}$ & $-$0.215$^{***}$ & $-$0.170$^{***}$ & $-$0.201$^{***}$ & $-$0.249$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  & (0.012) & (0.011) & (0.016) & (0.013) & (0.013) & (0.023) & (0.016) & (0.018) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 População &  &  & $-$0.024$^{***}$ & $-$0.026$^{***}$ & $-$0.042$^{***}$ & $-$0.036$^{***}$ & $-$0.617$^{***}$ & $-$0.013$^{***}$ & $-$0.140$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.198) & (0.005) & (0.043) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Renda per capita &  &  &  & 0.049$^{***}$ & 0.067$^{***}$ & 0.052$^{***}$ & 0.031 & 0.143$^{***}$ & 0.115$^{***}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.019) & (0.016) & (0.015) & (0.042) & (0.017) & (0.030) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Gasto em saúde e saneamento &  &  &  &  & 0.021$^{***}$ & 0.062$^{***}$ & 0.005 & 0.003 & $-$0.003 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.002) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.007) & (0.006) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Gasto em educação e cultura &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.045$^{***}$ & $-$0.004 & $-$0.003 & 0.001 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.007) & (0.005) & (0.007) & (0.005) \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
 Tendência (estado*ano) & 0.833$^{***}$ & 1.056$^{***}$ & 1.217$^{***}$ & 1.143$^{***}$ & 1.031$^{***}$ & 1.064$^{***}$ & $-$12.271$^{***}$ & $-$5.278$^{***}$ &  \\ 
  & (0.004) & (0.011) & (0.029) & (0.040) & (0.035) & (0.033) & (4.286) & (1.481) &  \\ 
  & & & & & & & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Efeito fixo de ano & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Efeito fixo de estado & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Efeito fixo de região & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Observations & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.660 & 0.844 & 0.857 & 0.860 & 0.904 & 0.914 & 0.984 & 0.941 & 1.000 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.659 & 0.843 & 0.856 & 0.859 & 0.903 & 0.913 & 0.981 & 0.939 & 1.000 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 0.057 (df = 376) & 0.039 (df = 375) & 0.037 (df = 374) & 0.037 (df = 373) & 0.031 (df = 372) & 0.029 (df = 371) & 0.013 (df = 318) & 0.024 (df = 362) & 0.016 (df = 344) \\ 
F Statistic & 729.946$^{***}$ (df = 1; 376) & 1,014.397$^{***}$ (df = 2; 375) & 749.786$^{***}$ (df = 3; 374) & 572.904$^{***}$ (df = 4; 373) & 699.079$^{***}$ (df = 5; 372) & 660.077$^{***}$ (df = 6; 371) & 335.396$^{***}$ (df = 59; 318) & 387.991$^{***}$ (df = 15; 362) & 23,712.990$^{***}$ (df = 34; 344) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{9}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: And how do you put an elephant into a refrigerator?  To fit this table you will need a font munch smaller than `\tiny` beside some other tricks to gain space! Do you think that this kind of table could be informative(I mean readable) to someone? Redesign the table. A elephant can be put in into a refrigerator ... but in pieces.

Comment: Welcome! Have you thought about how much of the details the audience will take home from this slide? At least I wouldn't like to sit in a talk in which such tables are shown. Please consider cutting the information down to pieces that the audience can parse and digest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I go into any details about how I'd adjust the table to make (parts of it) fit, I'd like to ask you the following question: What on earth are you trying to achieve by inflicting a table with 9 data columns and 7 main data rows (for a total of up to 108 numbers, counting all the standard errors) on your audience? Do you expect them to remember even one number? If not, why are you even considering overloading the audience of your talk with information which they cannot possibly take in?? Or, do you really want to be remembered by your audience as the guy (gal?) who takes sadistic pleasure in inflicting pointless amounts of numbers on his/her audience? I hope that your answer to the final question is an emphatic "no".

Anyway, you simply have way too much information in the table to fit inside a beamer page. You must cut back in quite a few places. For starters, I'd recommend getting rid of all degrees-of-freedom numbers (those are the ones your audience is really going to care about the most, aren't they??) and all asterisks. And, switch to `\tiny`, reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, and be less profligate with inter-row spacing, and don't use a `table` environment.

With all of these adjustments, it is possible -- but only just -- to make the table fit on a page.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Tabela 1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{9}{c} @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{9}{c}{Variável dependete: Anos de estudo (25 anos ou mais)} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-10} 
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9)\\ 
\midrule
\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\hsize}@{}}
  \raggedright Percentual de domicilios com abastecimento de água potável
\end{tabular}}
     & 0.739 & 0.287 & 0.308 & 0.286 & 0.196 & 0.203 & 0.136 & 0.196 & 0.332 \\ 
     & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.025) & (0.023) & (0.040) & (0.024) & (0.022) \\     
 Analfabestismo & & $-$0.247 & $-$0.246 & $-$0.216 & $-$0.202 & $-$0.215 & $-$0.170 & $-$0.201 & $-$0.249 \\ 
     & & (0.012) & (0.011) & (0.016) & (0.013) & (0.013) & (0.023) & (0.016) & (0.018) \\     
 População & & & $-$0.024 & $-$0.026 & $-$0.042 & $-$0.036 & $-$0.617 & $-$0.013 & $-$0.140 \\ 
     & & & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.198) & (0.005) & (0.043) \\     
 Renda per capita & & & & 0.049 & 0.067 & 0.052 & 0.031 & 0.143 & 0.115 \\ 
     & & & & (0.019) & (0.016) & (0.015) & (0.042) & (0.017) & (0.030) \\     
 Gasto em saúde e saneamento & & & & & 0.021 & 0.062 & 0.005 & 0.003 & $-$0.003 \\ 
     & & & & & (0.002) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.007) & (0.006) \\     
 Gasto em educação e cultura & & & & & & $-$0.045 & $-$0.004 & $-$0.003 & 0.001 \\ 
     & & & & & & (0.007) & (0.005) & (0.007) & (0.005) \\    
 Tendência (estado$\times$ano) & 0.833 & 1.056 & 1.217 & 1.143 & 1.031 & 1.064 & $-$12.27 & $-$5.278 & \\ 
     & (0.004) & (0.011) & (0.029) & (0.040) & (0.035) & (0.033) & (4.286) & (1.481) & \\ 
\midrule
Efeito fixo de ano & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Efeito fixo de estado & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Efeito fixo de região & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Não & Sim \\ 
Observations & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 & 378 \\ 
\smash{R\textsuperscript{2}} & 0.660 & 0.844 & 0.857 & 0.860 & 0.904 & 0.914 & 0.984 & 0.941 & 1.000 \\ 
Adjusted \smash{R\textsuperscript{2}} & 0.659 & 0.843 & 0.856 & 0.859 & 0.903 & 0.913 & 0.981 & 0.939 & 1.000 \\ 
Residual Std.\ Error & 0.057 & 0.039 & 0.037 & 0.037 & 0.031 & 0.029 & 0.013 & 0.024 & 0.016 \\ 
F Statistic & 729.9 & 1,014.4 & 749.8 & 572.9 & 699.1 & 660.1 & 335.4 & 388.0 & 23,713 \\ 
\bottomrule
%\addlinespace
%\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\textit{Note:} $^{*}\,p<0.1$; $^{**}\,p<0.05$; $^{***}\,p<0.01$} \\ 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* with some additional suggestion on how to make your table more easily readable.

- Something seems to be wildly off in the *final column*: the simple and adjusted R-squared stats are both equal to 1 and the value of the regression F-statistic is simply astronomical. (By the way, I'm an econometrician.) To my eyes, it looks like you made a mistake in that regression; my hunch is that by including a complete set of age, state, and region fixed effects, you succeeded in making the regression "explain" the entire variance of the dependent variable. What's the upshot? Unless you can figure out what went wrong and correct the mistake, you should almost certainly omit the final column entirely.
- Since each regression is based on hundreds and hundreds of observations, the values of the simple and adjusted R-squared statistics are very very close to each other. Reporting both is an exercise in redundancy. In order not to insult the intelligence of your readers, don't show *both* statistics.
- All regression F-statistics are highly significant. In fact, they are so highly significant that no discernable purpose is served by showing them separately. A simple sentence, in which you mention that all F-statistics are significant, should easily suffice.
- Similarly, I fail to see any reason for showing the "Residual Std. Error" row.
- Since each and every regression has the same number of underlying observations, *viz.*, 378, it seems pointless to devoting an entire row to highlighting this not-exactly-hugely-exciting fact. Just mention in the legend that all regressions are based on 378 observations; that'll be far more helpful to your readers.
- If you can get rid of the suspicious final column, there will be enough space to align the numbers in the remaining 8 data columns on their respective decimal markers.
- Still on the topic of getting rid of the suspicious final column: If you can get rid of it, you can delete three more rows: the ones that would show that none of the other 8 regressions include any fixed-effect regressors.
- I mentioned above that a compelling reason for leaving off the significance-denoting asterisks is that there's just no room for them. A second compelling reason for not showing the asterisks is that in every single instance where the coefficients are significant, there are *always three* asterisks; there's not a single instance of a coefficient with one- or two-asterisk significance. Hence marking the coefficient with a single asterisk (and adjusting the legend to announce that a single asterisk denotes significance at the one-percent level) should be more than enough. Showing one asterisk instead of three will really reduce the visual clutter. However, I wouldn't go the asterisk route at all. If you simply *must* highlight the fact that some coefficients, I suggest you do so by coloring the cells in blue (or violet, if you prefer).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,siunitx,}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\color' and '\textcolor' macros

\newcommand\CC{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Tabela 1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\sisetup{input-symbols         = ( ), 
         table-space-text-post = ),
         table-format          = -1.3}
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{8}{S} @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{Variável dependete: Anos de estudo (25 anos ou mais)} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-9} 
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\ 
\midrule
\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\hsize}@{}}
  \raggedright Percentual de domicilios com abastecimento de água potável
\end{tabular}}
     &\CC0.739 &\CC0.287 &\CC0.308 &\CC0.286 &\CC0.196 &\CC0.203 &\CC0.136 &\CC0.196\\ 
     & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.027) & (0.028) & (0.025) & (0.023) & (0.040) & (0.024)\\ 
\addlinespace    
 Analfabestismo & &\CC-0.247 &\CC-0.246 &\CC-0.216 &\CC-0.202 &\CC-0.215 &\CC-0.170 &\CC-0.201\\ 
     & & (0.012) & (0.011) & (0.016) & (0.013) & (0.013) & (0.023) & (0.016)\\     
\addlinespace    
 População & & &\CC-0.024 &\CC-0.026 &\CC-0.042 &\CC-0.036 &\CC-0.617 &\CC-0.013\\ 
     & & & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.198) & (0.005)\\     
\addlinespace    
 Renda per capita & & & &\CC0.049 &\CC0.067 &\CC0.052 & 0.031 &\CC0.143\\ 
     & & & & (0.019) & (0.016) & (0.015) & (0.042) & (0.017)\\     
\addlinespace    
 Gasto em saúde e saneamento & & & & &\CC0.021 &\CC0.062 & 0.005 & 0.003\\ 
     & & & & & (0.002) & (0.006) & (0.005) & (0.007)\\     
\addlinespace    
 Gasto em educação e cultura & & & & & &\CC-0.045 & -0.004 & -0.003\\ 
     & & & & & & (0.007) & (0.005) & (0.007)\\    
\addlinespace    
 Tendência (estado$\times$ano) &\CC0.833 &\CC1.056 &\CC1.217 &\CC1.143 &\CC1.031 &\CC1.064 &\CC-12.271 &\CC-5.278\\ 
     & (0.004) & (0.011) & (0.029) & (0.040) & (0.035) & (0.033) & (4.286) & (1.481)\\ 
\midrule
R\textsuperscript{2} & 0.660 & 0.844 & 0.857 & 0.860 & 0.904 & 0.914 & 0.984 & 0.941\\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{Number of observations for all regressions: 378. No age, state[estado?], or region fixed effects. Coefficients colored in \textcolor{blue}{blue} are statistically significant at the 1\% level. All regression F-statistics are statistically significant at the 1\% level.}\\ 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a master's cadidate in Economics and this is the result of work that I'm doing for the end of the semester. The ideia of work with 9 data columns is to show that the coefficient  of my first independent variable keeps statistically significant. I've seen this strategy in many articles and then I thought about doing the same thing, but I'll consider make some changes.

Comment: Extra +1 for a really good explanation as to what to leave out.

Comment: @MateusMaciel - Please see the addendum I posted, in which I suggest some further simplifications.